# Where can I download the distribution of mediawiki including all the wikipedia extensions?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

[Extraction of Reusable Structured Data from Wikipedia](http://db-event.jpn.org/deim2011/proceedings/pdf/f3-4.pdf)
In this article, it is said that there is wmf4, mediawiki distribution including all the wikipedia extensions, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pre-built package with all extensions used in Wikimedia wikis, so the easiest way would be to clone the latest wmf-branch of MediaWiki (which is thought to be used in Wikimedia wikis and/or experienced users, only and may contain bugs for third party users) from the git repository and initialize the git submodules. So, to use the latest wmf version, 1.27.0-wmf.1, (which is currently used on Wikimedia test wikis, only, see [the roadmap](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_1.27/Roadmap) for the actual deployment status) you coulduse git:

```
git clone https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/mediawiki/core
cd core
git checkout wmf/1.27.0-wmf.1
git submodule update --init
```

After that you should have the actual copy of MediaWiki in the `core` directory (you can look at the contents [on github](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/tree/wmf/1.27.0-wmf.1), too). But think about, that wmf-versions aren't officially supported by the MediaWiki developers, but we welcome any bug report.

Btw.: You could clone the latest stable version (currently MediaWiki 1.25.X) and install all extensions you want, manually. A list of actual deployed extensions to Wikimedia wikis can be found [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/operations-mediawiki-config/blob/master/wmf-config/extension-list).

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/mediawiki/extensions
cd extensions
git submodule update --init
```

gets you all extensions hosted in Wikimedia's git repo. It's unlikely to be useful though. Also, I don't think extensions that are not used by Wikimedia have `wmf/...` branches.

Comment: Yes, only extensions, that are used in wmf wikis has a wmf/.. branch (but not all, some has a deploy branch only).